# IWindowManager is missing in Caliburn Micro namespace after upgrade

Tags: caliburn.micro, caliburn.micro.reactiveui

The project we were on used an older version of caliburn micro, we have upgraded to the current version and have found that the IWindowManager interface has gone!  Even crawling through the codeplex/github sites and searching here I can find no details as how you are supposed to mimic its methods.

What is the current practice?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caliburn.Micro.Platform might be missing in your references

WPF variant...
https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/blob/master/src/Caliburn.Micro.Platform/net40/WindowManager.cs

codeplex source is horribly unreliable now since they moved source to GitHub, I wouldn't rely on much there.